# Proof that $p_t(x,y)=(2\pi t)^{-d/2} e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t}}$ satisfies Chapman Kolmogorov.

Tags: integration, analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

For $x,y \in R^d$ let $p_t(x,y)=(2\pi t)^{-d/2} e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t}}$. Prove that $P_t(x,dy)=p_t(x,dy)$ satisfies the Chapman Kolmogorov equation. Below is the solution to this problem. My questions are : How do we come up with the below decomposition of the squares? I can't see the intuition behind coming up with such a completion of squares.

Second, what justifies the second equality at the end? When we make the change of variable to $\tilde{y}$, $\tilde{y}$ depends on $z$ so how is it fine to separate the iterated integral into two different integrals? I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One can also get this from the fact that this function is a fundamental solution of diffusion equation.

Answer (score 1):

They are simply [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) with respect to the $y$ variable. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Yes but in this case we have variables in $R^d$ and $|y-x|$ the euclidean norm. So I'm not sure how to work with the squares.

Comment: Use the fact that $|x|^2=x\cdot x$. The ordinary rules for calculations applies.